# command 'appscale up' stopped at 'Please wait for the AppController to finish pre-processing tasks.'

Tags: appscale

I installed AppScale on a VPS with 64-bit Ubuntu trusty and 4G RAM form source. Everytime I run command `appscale up`,it will stop at `Please wait for the AppController to finish pre-processing tasks.`. According to the [offical wiki](https://github.com/AppScale/appscale/wiki/Virtualized-Cluster) the next prompt will be `Please wait for AppScale to prepare your machines for use.` but it never occurs to me, **and there is no error**. Anybody knows where to get any log or how to solve this problem?

Here is the content of my `AppScalefile`:

```
---
ips_layout:
  master : 10.80.140.55 # this is the private IP of this VPS
  appengine : 10.80.140.55
  database : 10.80.140.55
  zookeeper : 10.80.140.55
login : here is the public IP of this vps

keyname : appscalec85934462268449a9c73b1dbd1bec4b9
group : appscalec85934462268449a9c73b1dbd1bec4b9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. Some packages failed to install because of the poor network in China, but I got no error report , so I mistaken that I installed successfully. after I finally installed these packages, it works

Answer (score 0):

Did you have any firewall or security group/network rules enables that prevent the host to contact itself via the public IP? With that configuration, the system needs to be able to access itself using the public IP.

One test you can do is to add the public IP locally to test, something like

ifconfig eth0:1 your_public_ip up

(substitute eth0 with your network interface and your_pubic_ip with whatever you put in the AppScalefile).

Comment: Do you know which port it used to contact itself, there's a firewall of server provider which blocked all ports except 22. And while I assign `my_public_ip` to `eth0` I got an error like:`SIOCSIFFLAGS: Cannot assign requested address`

Answer (score 0):

The controller sits on port 17443. I think it's the only one needed on recent version. If you have trouble creating users you may need to try the developer version so pull master.